# Searching for specific words in a text file

Tags: c, text-files, fgets, fputs

HI guys havent been able to find how to search for specific words in a text file anywhere, so here it goes, this is what I have now and just read and prints the entire text file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main ( void )
{

static const char filename[] = "chat.log";
FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );
if ( file != NULL )
{ 
char line [ 128 ]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) /* read a line */
{

fputs ( line, stdout ); /* write the line */
} 
fclose ( file );
}

else
{
perror ( filename ); /* why didn't the file open? */
}
return 0;
}
```

Thank you :D

Comment: correct `fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL` , `sizeof(line)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `strstr(line, word)` to look for the word anywhere inside the line. If `strstr` returns non-NULL, it means the current line contains your word.

Comment: Where to write it though? :)

Comment: @Winkz In the test clause of an `if` statement! :)

Comment: hmm im gd rusty atm.. like this {
if(strstr(line, damage){
fputs ( line, stdout ); /* write the line */
}
}

Comment: @Winkz Compilation or run-time error? Please note that StackOverflow is not a helpdesk; if you have a specific problem, feel free to ask it in the form of a new question. Also, please remember to upvote good answers and accept the one that helped you solve your problem, if any. This gesture rewards the volunteers writing the answers.

Answer (score 1):

your approach would work but it's a bit naive and you could do far better than that.

here's an excellent algorithm for string searching: [Boyer–Moore string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

When searching for a fixed set of words, I suggest you have a look at the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm). It's really good in terms of performance.